# How to implement access controls for Chef Knife SSH

Tags: chef-infra

I want to use Knife SSH to manage our servers to replace traditional SSH session. But I still have

1. How to implement controls for who can use Knife SSH?
2. How to control the Linux command level access in Knife SSH?
3. How is the executed commands logged? Is there a way to centralize all the logs for audit purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knife ssh` isn't really its own thing, it uses actual normal SSH connections so you would have to use whatever your SSH daemon provides. For OpenSSH this would generally be `ForceCommand` either at the server or authorized_keys level and then one of many available filtering scripts. If you poke around on github I'm sure you can find some examples of filtering or audit scripts, or you can look at the docs and build one yourself, it's not that hard.